# google maps api count

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to wrap my head around what counts against the API call quota.
I have a page with a map, the map has 5000 locations marked on it.

Does google count the 1 page load or the 5000 locations it marked on the map?

Comment: Just read, it's [there](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq?hl=en#usage_mapload) + your question is off topic as it is not about programming.

Comment: not related to programming. this is more like an inquiry for google maps api. but to answer your question, it will count as one map load after successfully loading the map. drawings on map, such as polygons, shapes and markers does not count as map load. interactions such as click, hover, drag and zoom in/out also does not count.

Comment: @tomjosef, that's what i figured, good enough for me if you want to make it the answer.

Comment: @vector - Sure. Added now with more details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the answer to this in the new documentation [**Understanding Billing for Maps, Routes, and Places**](https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/understanding-cost-of-use#billing-overview)

From the [SKU: Dynamic Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/understanding-cost-of-use#dynamic-maps)

> A web page or application that displays a map using the Maps JavaScript API. A map is created with the `google.maps.Map()` class.
>
> User interactions with the map, such as panning, zooming, or switching map layers, do not generate additional map loads.

This also mean that [Drawing on the Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays) does not count as map load since it does not need to call the `google.maps.Map()` for each overlay.

However, if you are retrieving the latitude and longitude for a place or street address with **Places Library** or **Geocoding Service** to display the markers, then it means you are making a request using those APIs and will be charged separately.

If your Javascript Map instantiates a Street View, this will also be charged separately as per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/understanding-cost-of-use#dynamic-street-view)

> In JavaScript, with the google.maps.StreetViewPanorama() class or Map.getStreetView() method (prior to the new pricing, Map.getStreetView() was not charged). Usage of the StreetViewService() class is not charged.

Hope this helped!

Comment: thanks, I think this is the spot I need to look at closely: calls to "Places Library or Geocoding Service"